# Global name error for using feed_dict for making predictions in retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, global-variables, prediction

I run the code

```
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.argmax(final_tensor, 1), feed_dict={resized_input_tensor: create_image_lists(testing_images)}))
```

in retrain.py (I have also tried the code without create_image_lists in feed_dict) right after final_tensor is set (line 776 is where my code is inserted) and receive the error

```
NameError: global name 'testing_images' is not defined
```

Testing images was used in feed_dict because to my understanding it is an array with all the images stored as some shape and that it will then become the input to final_tensor operations. If this is true, then I need to find a way to input in feed_dict.